# Wordpress recibir usuarios con rol X ordenados por apellido

Tags: php, wordpress

Como puedo obtener los usuarios con rol X ordenados por apellido alfabéticamente?

Actualmente uso `WP_User_Query()` pero si añado un rol no me los ordena por apellido.

```
$args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'last_name',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'role'=>$department
        );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Al añadir el parámetro **role** en la query, los usuarios que obtengo, que son correctos, no están ordenados por **meta_key** **last_name**.

Según la [documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) deberían salirme ordenados por la **meta_key** que he establecido.

Comment: ¿Si quitas esto `'role'=>$department` sí salen ordenados?

Comment: Prueba a pasar los datos relativos al orden dentro de un sub-array, algo así: `$args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'last_name',
           array ( 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'ASC' ),
            'role'=>$department
        );`